# Collision between boost::numeric::ublas::vector and std::vector in clang-503.0.40

Tags: c++, boost, stl, clang, c++03

So I have a piece of code that I'm trying to compile on an older machine that relies on both `std::vector` for data storage and `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` for linear algebra purposes.  Both are fully disambiguated in the code; attempting to create a variable of type `vector` fails (I do have a namespace alias `namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;` in the header for sanity). When I attempt to compile this code on a newer Mac running clang-600.0.56, it compiles fine, but when I try to compile it on an older Mac running clang-503.0.40, it fails to compile. The error message I receive is:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:129:35: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > >'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114:21: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::iterator_traits<boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double, std::allocator<double> > > >' requested here
inline typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type
                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:115:5: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'distance' [with _InputIterator = boost::numeric::ublas::vector<double, boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<double,
  std::allocator<double> > >]
distance(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
```

This is at the end of a chain of includes stepping through boost and then into the STL. I'm 99% certain this is a problem related to disambiguation of `std::vector` and `ublas::vector`, as `iterator_category` is a member of the former and not of the latter. As further evidence, we have code that uses `std::vector` and code that uses `ublas::vector` that all compiles fine but we don't appear to have any code in our codebase that relies on both until now.

Has anybody run into a similar issue before and found a way to resolve it that does not involve stripping either the `std::vector` or `ublas::vector` dependencies from my code or updating the compiler?

Both machines use boost-1.48.0 and I am limited to C++03 on both.

Comment: MCVE, please. Crystal balls are out of service today.

Comment: I'll bet there's a `using namespace std;` mess, in here.

Comment: @SergeyA trying to make one for you, hang on

Comment: @SamVarshavchik not in the in-house code, at the very least. Only if boost does it somewhere :/

Comment: @SergeyA I can't seem to figure out an MCVE for this problem, which is odd. Simple code that uses both kinds of vectors appears to compile fine. I'll dig into my code a bit more and see if I can isolate the problem further.

Comment: Well, I figured out the problem. Turns out that I had a function called `distance` in my own namespace `transform`, and for some reason the older version of clang thought that I wanted to call `std::distance` instead of `transform::distance`.

Thanks for your help, everybody.